# Real Time OBJECT DETECTION using Python, OpenCV, MobileNet SSD and Tensor Flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

i just try to implement my trained model with `tensorflow2` in pycharm ,i use :
`ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8` .

this is the code I use :

```py
# OBJECT DETECTOR
import cv2  # OpenCV
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

configfile = "label_map.pbtxt"  # Config File for Trained MobileNet SSD Model
frozen_model = "export/export/saved_model/saved_model.pb"  # Weighhts - derived from tensor flow
        
model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(frozen_model, configfile)
```

and i got this error :

```
model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(frozen_model, configfile)  # Model usedto Detect Objects SystemError: <class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> 
returned a result with an error set.
```

Please if you get this error before tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to load the model using the `.pb` and the `.pbtxt` config files?

You need to use the correct function to load the model:

```
model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(frozen_model, configfile)
```

Comment: yes that's right ,i aready try this one but it doesn't  work it give me also an error .